# Problema de Recursividade em Python

Tags: python

É minha primeira dúvida aqui, então serei breve: Estou com problema no código abaixo:

```
def nat(n):
  if n == 50:
     return 0
  else:
     return nat(n+1)
print(nat(1))
```

Acontece que é uma questão recursiva em Python, devo imprimir os 50 primeiros números naturais, porém minha saída sempre retorna '0':

```
0
```

Não entendo quase nada sobre o assunto, já resolvi a questão em C e em Python, mas usando estruturas de repetição, porém dessa forma que me foi apresentada, não estou conseguindo resolver o mesmo problema. Alguém tem uma orientação de onde está o erro(s)?
Lembrete, não preciso da resolução do problema, apenas de um guia de onde estou errando, se possível.

Comment: Existem dois retornos na função `n`: um retorna uma chamada recursiva, sem alterar seu resultado em nada; o outro retorna 0, simplesmente. Assim, você pode retornar 0 ou retornar a computação de algo sem aplicar nenhuma mudança, e essa computação sempre retorna 0. (Estou ignorando entradas maiores que 50, que seriam infinitas e jamais retornariam)

Comment: Não ficou muito claro pra mim, dessa forma, poderia dar uma exemplificação, amigo?(Como citei acima, sou um tanto quanto leigo, rs)

Comment: Segundo sua função, vou pegar a partir de 48 e verificar o valor resultante, `nat(48) ==> nat(48+1) ==> nat(48+1+1) ==> 0`

Comment: Ahh, obrigado amigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu código você está fazendo o seguinte:

```
#define a  função nat
def nat(n):
    if n == 50:
        return 0
    else:
        return nat(n+1)

#chama a função para printar o valor retornado
print(nat(1))
```

Até aí tudo certo, o retorno está de acordo com o que você descreveu.

Você chama a função com valor `n=1`, como o valor de `n` não é igual a `50` vai retornar o valor de `nat(n=2)`, e assim por diante até no fim das contas `n=50` e retorna `0`, que é o valor printado.

Portanto, no seu código: `nat(1) = nat(2) = nat(3) = ... = nat(50) = 0`

Acredito que seja um pequeno problema de endentação com uns pequenos ajustes.

Acho que seria isso ,ou algo próximo, o que você quer fazer:

```
#Define a função
def nat(n):
    if n == 50:
        return
    else:
        #printa e faz a chamada recursiva
        print(n)
        nat(n+1)

#chama a função
nat(1)
```

Comment: Sim, funcionou perfeitamente, era exatamente isso, porém ele para em 49, mas pra isso foi só ajudar o caso base de 50 para 51... Eu estava vacilando,  nunca iria dar o valor certo, sempre iria retornar '0', pois eu estava atribuindo 0 ao retorno na condição do caso base, haha. Eu não estava sabendo endentar de forma correta. Obrigado amigão, foi de grande ajuda =D